# sbt dependency root catalog differs from intellij libraries after import

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, directory, sbt

I'm using Scala plugin version 1.3.3 for Intellij 14.0.3 at my work computer and have started a new SBT project from scratch without any hassle.
But my problems starts right here where build.sbt file have compile errors in Intellij, it can not resolve any line of code. I can how ever auto import by changing the build.sbt file and adding a library dependencies..

So I tested to add scalatest which is downloaded to an .ivy2 directory, but a totaly different one that Intellij are using.

[image: build.sbt file]

This is how ever how my project structure are looking like, every libs have an error due to wrong path.

[image: project structure]

And here is where SBT plugin is locating all of it's dependencies and scala libs.

[image: Scala sbt plugin adds to wrong directory]

I know how to change where .ivy2 directory will be stored by adding these two parameters to

Settings -> Build,Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> SBT -> JVM Options -> VM parameters

```
-Dsbt.ivy.home=c:/.ivy2

-Dsbt.home=c:/.ivy2
```

But it only works for .iv2 folders and not the .sbt folders that are also in the wrong place. I believe that's the cause of why I can't resolve the symbols in the build.sbt script.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I just can have one directory for both Scala plugin and Itellij project files?